# yum update fails: _rpm.error: invalid header data

Tags: yum, rpm

I am trying to update a package, but it fails with what appears to be a rpm database error - is there a way to repair this?

```
bash-4.2# yum update icinga2
...
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 375, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 281, in main
    return_code = base.doTransaction()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 817, in doTransaction
    resultobject = self.runTransaction(cb=cb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 1818, in runTransaction
    self.plugins.run('pretrans')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 188, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/show-leaves.py", line 40, in pretrans_hook
    _old_leaves = _get_installed_leaves(conduit)
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/show-leaves.py", line 34, in _get_installed_leaves
    for po in conduit.getRpmDB().returnLeafNodes():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 1296, in returnLeafNodes
    return [ self._makePackageObject(h, mi) for (h, mi) in ts.returnLeafNodes(headers=True) ]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpmUtils/transaction.py", line 174, in returnLeafNodes
    for p in _return_all_provides(h):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpmUtils/transaction.py", line 166, in _return_all_provides
    for prov in hdr[rpm.RPMTAG_FILENAMES]:
_rpm.error: invalid header data
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix a corrupted RPM database

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb

yum clean all
```

Comment: No, that didn't work - we have tried a number of things, even looking in the python code, but that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this error message today.  In my case it was a problem with the corruption of stored package metadata for locally installed packages.

If it is a local package issue the offending package(s) can be identified with the following command.  It will print `_rpm.error: invalid header data` immediately after the the name of the packages which have issues.  Note this will take a while to run and will print out the name of every installed package.

```
repoquery --disablerepo='*' -a --installed | \
xargs -t -n1 repoquery --disablerepo='*' --list --installed | \
grep '_rpm.error: invalid header data'
```

Reinstalling the packages with `_rpm.error` after them resolved the problem for me.

```
yum reinstall -y <offending-packages>
```

I have also come across a very similar error when the repo has corrupt metadata or corrupt rpm files.  If you have access you can identify the corrupt rpms with:

```
find /path/to/repo/root -name '*.rpm' | \
xargs rpm -K | \
grep 'NOT OK'
```

To resolve remove these rpms and update the repo metadata, re-sync from the source if needed.

```
rm /path/to/bad/rpm
createrepo --update /path/to/repo/root
```